# how to receive emails using pop3 in php

Tags: php, pop3

in my php web application, i want to retrieve emails  using pop3.My application allows to send messages to emails or US cell numbers , after sending the message, i want to retrieve the reply emails or reply messages from cell numbers.For sending messages a unique id is used for each users. Reply can be sent to this ID. I don't know how to possible?. I am new with php mailer. Anyone can help me. Advice me how is it in php.

Answer (score 2):

The native PHP IMAP functions support POP3 mailboxes. Check PHP manual for IMAP functions [PHP IMAP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php)

Other options are

- PEAR's POP3 class
- Use PHPClasses [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Give you a PEAR class library for example:

```
<?php
require_once('Net/POP3.php');

$pop3 =& new Net_POP3;
$pop3->connect('localhost', 110);
$pop3->login('popuser', 'poppassword', false);
$msgCnt = $pop3->numMsg(); 
$headers = $pop3->getParsedHeaders($msgCnt); 
$from = mb_decode_mimeheader($headers['From']);
$subject = mb_decode_mimeheader($headers['Subject']);
$content = $pop3->getBody($msgCnt); 
$pop3->disconnect(); 

echo "From: $from\n";
echo "Subject: $subject\n";
echo "Body: $content\n";

?>
```

Installation library command

Pear install Net_Pop3

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know that it is even an option, most mail servers will allow you to pipe any email  sent to a script as it comes in. This way you get email responses immediately, and without having to run a cron job, or wait to process them until someone loads a page.

You would have to ask your mail host how to set it up, but once you have mail going to a PHP script you can use the PHP Mime Mail Parser library to parse the message and then do whatever you need with it.

```
require_once('MimeMailParser.class.php');

$Parser = new MimeMailParser();
$Parser->setStream(fopen("php://stdin", "r"));

$to = $Parser->getHeader('to');
$from = $Parser->getHeader('from');
$subject = $Parser->getHeader('subject');
$text = $Parser->getMessageBody('text');
$html = $Parser->getMessageBody('html');
$attachments = $Parser->getAttachments();
```

https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/